# RecyclerView OnItemClick open different activity depending on where the inquiry came from

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, oneclick

[[image: OneClickTwoOptions]]

I have a list of categories and list of products, going directly to the list of categories and clicking on the Item in `RecyclerView` redirects me to the activity where I can edit the category, and follow if it is possible that when adding a new product I want to select the category for this product and to redirect to the list of categories I want to click on the item of RecyclerView redirects me to activity with product, adding Category to the product.
This fragment of my code:
**AddProduct-Activity**

```
private void openProdCategory() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AddProduct.this, ProdCatList.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, GET_CATEGORY_REQUEST);
}
```

**CategoryLisy-Activity**

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra(String.valueOf(AddProduct.GET_CATEGORY_REQUEST))) {
        prodCatAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ProdCatAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Prod_Cat prodCat) {

                Intent data = new Intent(ProdCatList.this, AddProduct.class);
                data.putExtra(EXTRA_PROD_CATID, prodCat.getProdCatId());
                data.putExtra(EXTRA_PROD_CATNAME, prodCat.getCategoryName());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });
    } else {
        prodCatAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ProdCatAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Prod_Cat prodCat) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProdCatList.this, AddCatProd.class);
                intent.putExtra(AddCatProd.EXTRA_CATID, prodCat.getProdCatId());
                intent.putExtra(AddCatProd.EXTRA_CATTITLE, prodCat.getCategoryName());
                intent.putExtra(AddCatProd.EXTRA_CATDESCRIPTION, prodCat.getCategoryDescription());
                intent.putExtra(AddCatProd.EXTRA_CATPRIOR, String.valueOf(prodCat.getCategoryPriority()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_CATPROD_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You're forgetting the question...

Comment: Also, post the code for your recycler view